# How do I stop a distribution upgrade from upgrading PHP?

Tags: upgrade, php

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu server to 12.04 - it was completed with just one "problem".

PHP has been reinstalled to 5.3.10 from Ubuntu's repos. and I wanted to keep my php package from dotdeb.org. Before I start with upgrade my second server, is there any way to disable php upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do a package "Hold"

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages

Basically you want to do something like:

```
echo php5-common hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

And when you're ready to upgrade PHP:

```
echo php5-common install | dpkg --set-selections
```

If you want to keep using dotdeb updates that come in, and stay off the Ubuntu packages, you want full Apt Pinning, but that is rather complicated (see the PinningHowto linked above).